# WSO2 ESB cluster: Are workers able to reconnect after ELB dies?

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, esb

I have read the tutorial about the WSO2 ESB cluster, I wonder if is there anyway for ESB worker/manager automatically reconnect to ELB when ELB restarts?

Answer (score 1):

The worker/manager nodes join the cluster at the startup. There is no such a way for worker/manager nodes to connect to the cluster when the ELB restarts. But you can configure multiple WKA members in a cluster such as manager, ELB. Then if the ELB goes down manager node will become the well known member in the cluster. When the ELB restarts you may see in the manager's console a notification message saying member joined with the specified port.